# Sabre SOAP API using cURL

Tags: php, curl, sabre

Is there any example for creating session using SOAP API (cURL)? I need an example to create session using cURL.

```
$input_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
        <eb:ConversationId/>
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
        <wsse:UsernameToken> 
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
            <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain> 
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
    <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple"/>
    </eb:Manifest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$action = 'SessionCreateRQ';
$url = 'https://webservices.sabre.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapXML);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $data;
}
```

I got this error:

> soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessageUnable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 2 of document : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 2 of document : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SabreAPI {
    const SOAP_XML_FOLDER = 'soapxml';
    const SOAP_API_URL = 'https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com';

    protected $_userName = '<hidden>';
    protected $_password = '<hidden>';
    protected $_ipcc = '<hidden>';

    protected $_soapToken = '';

    protected function _soapSendRequest($action, $xml)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml),
            'Accept: text/xml',
            'Keep-Alive: 300',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Pragma: no-cache',
            'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::SOAP_API_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_error($ch)) {
            throw new \Exception("Curl error: ".curl_error($ch));
        } else {
            return $this->_parseSoapAnswer($data, $action, $xml);
        }
    }

    public function soapOpenSession()
    {

        $action = 'SessionCreateRQ';
        $soapXML = $this->_getSoapXml($action, [
            'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'),
            'userName' => $this->_userName,
            'password' => $this->_password,
            'ipcc' => $this->_ipcc,
        ]);

        $token = $this->_soapSendRequest($action, $soapXML);

        if ($token !== false) {
            $this->_soapToken = $token;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getSoapXml($xmlName, $params = []) 
    {
        $filePath = self::SOAP_XML_FOLDER . '/' . $xmlName . '.xml';

        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            throw new \Exception("\AviaAPI\Sabre\SabreAPI::_getSoapXmlAuth(\'{$xmlName}\') XML file not found");
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($filePath);

        foreach ($params as $paramName => $paramVal) {
            $xml = str_replace('%'.$paramName.'%', $paramVal, $xml);
        }
        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Parsing SOAP Answer
     * @param string $soapAnswer
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function _parseSoapAnswer($soapAnswer, $soapAction, $xml)
    {
    //del soap prefix
        $soapAnswer = str_replace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'soap-env:', 'eb:', 'wsse:', 'stl:', 'tir39:'], '', $soapAnswer);
        $soapAnswer = simplexml_load_string($soapAnswer);

        $body = $soapAnswer->Body;
        $header = $soapAnswer->Header;

        //check error
        if (isset($body->Fault))
        {
            $faultCode = (string)$body->Fault->faultcode;
            $faultString = (string)$body->Fault->faultstring;

            trigger_error("\AviaAPI\Sabre\SabreAPI SOAP Failed. Server return error: {$faultCode}: {$faultString}", E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }

        if ($soapAction == "SessionCreateRQ")
        {
            $BinarySecurityToken = (string)$header->Security->BinarySecurityToken;
            return $BinarySecurityToken;
        }

        $answer = '';

        if (isset($body->CompressedResponse))
        {
            //decompress answer
            $decodedAnswer = base64_decode($body->CompressedResponse);
            $answer = simplexml_load_string(gzdecode($decodedAnswer), "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        }
        else
        {
            $answer = $body;
        }

        if (isset($answer->Errors->Error))
        {
            $lastError = (string)$answer->Errors->Error[(count($answer->Errors->Error) - 1)]["ShortText"];
            $lastError .= "; " . (string)$answer->Errors->Error[(count($answer->Errors->Error) - 2)]["ShortText"];

            trigger_error("\AviaAPI\Sabre\SabreAPI Server return error: {$lastError}", E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }

        return $answer;
    }
}
```

And SessionCreateRQ.xml put into soapxml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>%ipcc%</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-%ipcc%</ConversationId>
            <Service>SessionCreate</Service>
            <Action>SessionCreateRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>%timestamp%</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>%userName%</Username>
                <Password>%password%</Password>
                <Organization xmlns="">%ipcc%</Organization>
                <Domain xmlns="">DEFAULT</Domain>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <SessionCreateRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11">
            <POS>
                <Source PseudoCityCode="%ipcc%"/>
            </POS>
        </SessionCreateRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about cURL but the XML is not entirely correct.

You have:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
        <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="cid:rootelement" xlink:type="simple"/>
    </eb:Manifest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But it should be:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SessionCreateRQ returnContextID="true">
        <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="IPCC"/>
        </POS>
    </SessionCreateRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The Manifest element is meant to be used when handling SOAP with attachments, which does not seem to be the case.